# Change the font size in Automatic plot legending

Tags: legending

How can I change the font size in automatic legending?

For example, In the attached image, I would like the numbering to be shown with the size of 18pt or so and bold. I am using the following script but not it does not give what I expect.

[image]

```
ListPointPlot3D[ccmp, 
 PlotLegends -> 
  PointLegend[Automatic, LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 20, Bold}] ]
```

Comment: You may need to specify them explicity, like `PlotLegends -> {Style[1, Bold, 22], Style[2, Bold, 22], 
  Style[3, Bold, 22]}`

Comment: `PlotLegends -> (Style[#, 22, Bold] & /@ Range[3])`

Answer (score 2):

`Placeholder`, which is what those legends are using, has a hard-coded font size.

There are a couple of possibilities I can think of:

- Use specific legend text, such as `PointLegend[{1, 2, 3}, LabelStyle -> {20, Bold}]`.  This will have a larger size text while leaving the size of the point marker the same:

[image]

- Use `LabelStyle -> {Magnification -> 2}` to set magnification, in which case the size of the point marker will also get larger, but you'll still have the placeholder legend labels:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Until we discover the right option to do this directly ...

We can post-process the legend object to modify the `Placeholder` labels:

```
ClearAll[modifyAutomaticLegendLabels, modifyLegend]

modifyAutomaticLegendLabels[style__, o : OptionsPattern[]] := 
 RawBoxes[ToBoxes[#] /. FrameBox[x_] :> FrameBox[StyleBox[x, style], o]] &

modifyLegend[style__, o : OptionsPattern[]] := # /. 
   l : _PointLegend | _LineLegend | _SwatchLegend :> 
        (modifyAutomaticLegendLabels[style, o]@l) &
```

***Examples:***

```
Row[modifyAutomaticLegendLabels[ 20, Red, Bold]@#[{Red, Green, Blue} , Automatic] & /@ 
  {PointLegend, LineLegend, SwatchLegend}, Spacer[20]]
```

[image]

```
modifyLegend[Red, 16]@
 ListPointPlot3D[RandomReal[100, {3, 100, 3}], 
  PlotLegends -> PointLegend[Automatic, LegendFunction -> "Panel"]]
```

[image]

```
modifyLegend[Red, 16, Plain, FrameStyle -> Directive[Thick, Green]]@
 Plot[{Sin[x], Cos[x], Cos[x] Sin[x]}, {x, 0, 2 Pi}, 
   PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

[image]